# Mismatched Timestamp after Query

Tags: datetime, google-sheets

I've found that sometimes comparing a timestamp on Google Sheets returned in a query differs from the original the query was based on.

At the online community I'm volunteering in, we use Google Forms to record volunteer hours. For our users to be able to verify their clock in/clock outs, we take the form responses with timestamps and filter them via a Query to only display those for one specific user:

```
=QUERY(A:F,"Select A,B,D where '"&J4&"'=F")
```

where J4 contains the username we are filtering for.

We calculate the row each stamp can be found in via a Match function where M2:M is the range containing the timestamp the query above returns and A2:A is the original timestamp.

```
=iferror(arrayformula(MATCH(M2:M,A2:A,0)+1),)
```

Now we found that sometimes, the MATCH failed even though we could verify that the timestamp in question existed. Some format wrangling later, we found the problem, illustrated for one example below:

The timestamp in question read `2/8/2018 4:12:47`. Converted to a decimal, the value in column A turned into `43139.1755413195`, while the *very same* time stamp in the query result read `43139.1755413194`. The very last decimal, invisible unless you change the format to number and look at the formula line at the top of the sheet, has changed.

We have several different time stamps where the last decimal in the query result differs from the original the query is based on. Whether the last decimal in the query was one higher or lower than the original was inconsistent.

For our sheet, we now implemented a workaround of truncating the number earlier. However, that seems very inelegant. Is there a more elegant solution or a way to prevent (what we assume to be) rounding errors like this from happening? My search of google and the forums has not turned up anything like it, though I'm having trouble phrasing it in a way that gives me relevant hits.

Comment: I suspect rounding errors are part of life, but what you could perhaps do is convert to decimals, then back with something like =text(your decimal here,"yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss") and match that text with corresponding texts generated the same way.

Comment: I still feel like this is a rounding error -- especially hidden in this way -- that should not be happening. I am not modifying the timestamp in any way, except select part of the responses via a Query...

Comment: Both those decimals evaluate to the same time down to the millisecond. I think it comes down to you cannot expect to match floating point that far out (and whoever implemented figures greater precision than to the millisecond is not needed). I deleted my other comments, which on reflection do not get to the heart of the issue.